# Print function in statement always return true

Tags: php, if-statement, printing

I have a question that really confuses me.
If I write a print function in the statement is always return true.
For example:

```
if (print('x') === 'y')
        echo 'true';
```

Now I know that is not how the things works and I should not write it, but I saw this question in another forum.

I checked it out and read that print always return 1, which mean it actually 1 === 'y' and still this should not echo true.

Any idea why is true?

Comment: Give operator precedence then see the output `<?php

if ((print('x')) === 'y')
    echo 'true';
?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your `print()` in `()` so that first print function executed then condition will be matched

```
<?php

if ((print('x')) === 'y')
        echo 'true';
```

https://3v4l.org/JtMFU